# Android Studio creates a test folder, why?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-testing

Android studio creates a test folder called androidTest with an ApplicationTest.java file by default upon creating a new project. It's obviously used for testing, but what kind of testing? In what circumstances should I use the test folder when developing an Android app?

Answer (score 2):

> but what kind of testing

The instrumentation testing that centers around the technologies in [the Testing Support Library](http://developer.android.com/tools/testing-support-library/index.html) (e.g., Espresso, UI Automator).

Answer (score 1):

You can do Android Instumentation Tests, or regular Junit4 testing. I recommend you do some kind of testing, if only to prevent regression of bugs. I favor test driven development (TDD), cf http://blog.pivotal.io/labs/labs/tdd-android-pov

Comment: How early in a project do you recommend to start testing? Do you have a good resource on preventing regression bugs?

Comment: In test driven development, you start writing a unit test, then you create the code. I do that in most of my projects. Just google for "java junit testing"